# Azure APIM publisher access control

Tags: azure-api-management

we have a common APIM setup where developer publishes and subscribes products. Can we restrict certain developers to only publish APIs under specific product. We don't want a developer tampering with the product published by another developer. I found a document where we can restrict the visibility from a subscribers perspective [link to doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-create-groups)

Can a similar access control can be done for a publishers?

Answer (score 0):

Look into ARM custom roles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles You should be able to create RBAC rules for your developers scoping access only to a certain products, since API membership in product is controlled by /products/{pid}/apis/{aid}

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called "groups" provided by azure, which will help us to group users and give privileges based on the roles(RBAC). Groups are further divided into two types
1.Default
2.Custom
A specific group of users can be given permissions edit to a specific product and only read some other product.

For Further reference follow the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-create-groups